# Number of solutions for $x[1] + x[2] + \ldots + x[n] =k$

Tags: combinatorics

Omg this is driving me crazy seriously, it's a subproblem for a bigger problem, and i'm stuck on it.

Anyways i need the number of ways to pick $x[1]$ ammount of objects type $1$, $x[2]$ ammount of objects type $2$, $x[3]$ ammounts of objects type $3$ etc etc such that $$x[1] + x[2] + \ldots x[n] = k\;.$$ Order of the objects of course doesn't matter.

I know there is a simple formula for this something like $\binom{k + n}n$ or something like that i just can't find it anywhere on google.

Comment: Pls use titles that describe the problem

Answer (score 3):

This is a so-called [stars-and-bars problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28probability%29); the number that you want is

$$\binom{n+k-1}{n-1}=\binom{n+k-1}k\;.$$

The linked article has a reasonably good explanation of the reasoning behind the formula.

Comment: @mikey: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The formula is:

$$ {n+k-1 \choose k} $$

Here's a proof:

Create a vector with $n$ ones and $k$ zeros, in no particular order. Each permutation of this vector is a solution to $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \cdots + x_k = n$. $x_1$ equals the number of ones to the left of the first zero, $x_2$ equals the number of ones between the first and second zeros, $x_3$ equals the number of ones between the second and third zeros, and so on, with the $x_i$ corresponding to the number of ones before the $(i-1)^{th}$ and $i^{th}$ zeros. There is a one-to-one correspondence between this permutation and $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \cdots + x_k = n$. There are $\dfrac{(n+k-1)!}{n!(k-1)!}$ permutations of such a vector, so hence the equation follows.

Answer (score 1):

$\tbinom{k+n}{n}$ is close...but not quite right:

For any pair of natural numbers $n$ and $k$, the number of distinct n-tuples of non-negative integers whose sum is $k$ is given by the binomial coefficient:
 $$\displaystyle\binom{n+k+1}{n - 1}= \binom{n + k - 1}{k},\quad \text{ where}\;\quad \binom{n+k-1}k\,=\,\frac{(n+k-1)\,!}{n\,!\,(k-1)\,!}\;$$

Your problem is a version of the classic "[*stars-and-bars problem*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28probability%29)" in combinatorics.

---

See [*Binomial Coefficient*](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDQQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient&ei=8HLoUPKPAcukqwGy5YCoAQ&usg=AFQjCNG6cvsMEtcHfsY-Fabj2lXhZDabgA&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.aWM) for more information on the very many ways the the binomial coefficient can be used, - when, why, and how it's appropriate for a problem like yours and many others!

Comment: This deserves a star! +1